# Glossy Buttons set color programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am currently trying the [Core Graphics 101: Glossy Buttons](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2134/core-graphics-101-glossy-buttons) by RAYWENDERLICH, but I am having a problem using it in my project, i don't know to apply this programmatically, and adjust its image programmatically.

Here is my button:

```
@interface CoolButtonViewController : UIViewController {
    CoolButton *_button;
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet CoolButton *button;



@implementation CoolButtonViewController
@synthesize button = _button;
```

How to edit the color of the image programmatically, not by slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is as simple as setting the button's hue, saturation, and brightness properties to whatever values you want.  (The values for these properties can range from 0.0 to 1.0)

```
_button.hue = 0.5;
_button.saturation = 0.5;
_button.brightness = 0.5;
```

Comment: are there any color list, I want to try a variety of colors.

Comment: @user This method will allow you to use literally any color. Play around with the color picker in Photoshop, or what ever program you use and apply the values to the above. However, adjusting the color to predetermined values is as simple as [UIColor blueColor] on the buttons background color property.